# Kitchen Ceiling Paint Keeps Bubbling

Tags: drywall, repair, kitchens, ceiling

Looking for some thoughts on why this keeps happening.
In September we moved into this new (to us) home - a 1956 ranch in the Detroit suburbs. About a month later I started noticing that the paint in the kitchen ceiling was starting to bubble, and we had some wet spots forming in bedroom ceilings at the other end of the house.

Seemed like the roof was clearly a problem. It was 10 years old but poorly done, so we got the roof replaced and that seemed to fix everything. I got the kitchen ceiling patched - parts of it were majorly flaking off and falling down - the contractor scraped off the bubbling paint and used joint compound to patch things up, then primed over it. No paint applied as yet.

However, I'm noticing that the kitchen ceiling is bubbling again, even where it was just patched. I can see no discernible leaks in the attics and given that the roof is brand new, I doubt there are issues there. I am trying to determine why this is happening now with a brand new, watertight roof.
Some additional information:

- The area is right above the stove, and we do a lot of cooking. Despite having a range hood, quite a bit of steam hits this area though I rarely see condensation forming on the ceiling.
- There is no insulation in the attic above our kitchen. Another problem that I will address in time, but perhaps the temp difference between 30 degree attic and hot kitchen generates more moisture on the ceiling surface...
- The kitchen ceiling has this weird layer on it that does not seem like drywall. Attaching a photo of what fell off before. The pink surface was attached to the ceiling and it's very thin - I have no idea what this is. The area that it came off of just seemed like more drywall.
- Again, no discernible moisture in the attic and the places where this is bubbling are dry to the touch.

Has anyone ever seen this? Does anyone know why this is happening? And how we can fix it once and for all?

[image]

[image: here's where it is in my kitchen]

[image: here's what's falling off the ceiling]

Comment: Even a quick and incomplete insulation job over the area would be a heck of a lot better than "nothing" in terms of condensation. Not to mention heat loss.

Comment: Feeling dry and being dry can be different.  Paint/primer also does not bond well with dust/dirt/oils on the surface, so prep work is 90% of a paint job.

Comment: Thank you. I can't understand why why there would be no insulation over this area when the rest of the house is in pretty good condition. Is there ever any practical purpose for _not_ insulating above a kitchen?

Comment: Maybe in a 24/7 restaurant in a hot climate.

Comment: Does the range hood vent to outside or into the roof space.

Comment: Range hood vents above the roof. The fan might need some work, when I moved in I realized that the sellers did not have a charcoal filter and the grease screen was entirely caked. Very gross.